# Calendar event distribution per year and day of week

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, spreadsheet, icalendar

I'm trying to build statistics of calendar events by hour and day of the week to see when a given calendar is usually "busy".

My dataset is a list of ICS events that looks like this (I'm generating columns (Year, Day-of-the-week, Hour-of-day) using formulas like (in Gsheets) `=Text(B2, "yyyy")`

| SUMMARY | DTSTART | Year | Day-of-week | Hour-of-day | DTEND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event A | 02/23/2020 2:00 PM | 2020 | Tuesday | 14 | 02/23/2020 5:00 PM |
| Event B | 05/23/2020 11:00 AM | 2020 | Tuesday | 14 | 02/23/2020 1:00 PM |

I found it quite straightforward to try to build a pivot table, using this as a starter

`row : ["year", "hour-of-the-day"]`

`column : ["day-of-the-week"]`

That looks like this : [image: Example calendar]

The tricky part is to build a dataset that allows me to count an event multiple times it it spans more than one hour

In the example above, event A is from 2:00 PM to 5PM, then I'd like this event to "count" for hours 14,15,16 (and maybe 17). So in a sense, "duplicate" the data for this event and show it for every hour thats between the start date and the end date (including/excluding the end date hour, I don't really care)

Any Idea how I could achieve that ? Ideally using google formulas (for example, in another sheet I would generate the same dataset, but duplicate each event for each hour of the day it spans, and use this new time as pivot values). I want to forward a spreadsheet template that does this and the end user only has to add/replace his list of calendar events in one sheet to have those statistics performed automatically.

*Note: if you know of free existing tools/ways to perform such calendar analytics, feel free to comment, but I was rather interested in how I could do this myself using pivot table tricks.*

Comment: A copy spreadsheet including an expected output will be helpful to provide an accurate answer

Comment: The screenshot I made is from my own personal data. Any suggestion where I could find a real public dataset ? Or just a couple fake data would be enough ?